# Borderlands 2 GOTY + Ultimate Vault Hunter Upgrade Pack 2, Is it now complete?

Tags: borderlands-2

I just bought BL2 GOTY edition. Now If I buy Ultimate Vault Hunter Upgrade Pack 2, my BL2 will have all current released DLC ?

Also what is playthrough?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes and no.  Yes, that seems to cover all of the important DLC, but no, the cosmetic DLC (character skins and the like) is not included.  Personally, I wouldn't be too concerned with that, as A) there's already a tonne of character customization options included in the game and major DLC; and B) it only effects how others see you (and what your hand looks like).

As for your second question, Borderlands and Borderlands 2 draws very heavily on Diablo 2 for leveling and character progression.  When you beat the game the first time, you still have lots of character  levels to unlock.  That's playthrough 1.  You can go back and play the game again with the same character on a harder difficulty.  That's playthrough 2, or True Vault Hunter mode (TVHM).  After beating TVHM, you can enter Ultimate Vault Hunter mode (UVHM), or playthrough 2.5, which has the same progress as your TVHM save, but ramps up the difficulty (and rewards) even higher.

Answer (score 1):

According to [Steam](http://store.steampowered.com/sub/32848/), the Borderlands 2 GOTY edition includes the following DLC:

- Captain Scarlett and her Pirate's Booty
- Psycho Pack
- Collecter's Edition Pack
- Creature Slaughterdome
- Mechromancer Pack
- Mr. Torgue's Campaign of Carnage
- Sir Hammerlock's Big Game Hunt
- Tiny Tina's Assault on Dragon Keep
- Ultimate Vault Hunters Upgrade Pack

In addition to the Ultimate Vault Hunter Upgrade Pack 2 and plenty of cosmetic/costume DLC for characters, there is some mission DLC that is not included in the GOTY edition. As of this writing this includes:

- Headhunter 1: Bloody Harvest
- Headhunter 2: Wattle Gobbler
- Headhunter 3: Mercenary Day
- Headhunter 4: Wedding Day Massacre
- Headhunter 5: Son of Crawmerax

I would guess that these DLCs aren't very big, because they normally sell for $3.

Comment: TY. I guess i can count it as full completed. Who need those heads :D

Comment: Two more Headhunter DLCs have since been released, *Wedding Day Massacre* and *Son of Crawmerax*. No more DLC packs are expected for *Borderlands 2* (*Borderlands: The Pre-Sequel* will be released on October 17).

Comment: @DragonLord I added those to the list, thanks for letting me know. :)